# Update chrome extension icon on tab switch/change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My extension is relevant only for a few websites. So, it has a normal icon that is shown on the toolbar (browser action) and when user opens a site that is supported the icon should change to a different one to indicate it. Same thing should happen when the user switches tabs. I tried setting up a background page and sending message to the popup page like below,

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {         
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg: 'supported'});
});
```

**popup**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, messageSender, sendResponse) {
  updateIcon();
});
```

But it is not working. The updateIcon() function is fine as it works when called from popup page. I am new to chrome extension development, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a page action?   Those are intended for extensions relevant to only a few sites.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to get it done by content scripts to detect the switch on a supported page, then notify the background page in order to display a browser action icon for that page. Your content script should send a message using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, and the background page should listen using `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`:

I created the sample code and tested it works with me:

Content script:

```
if(onSupportedPageNeedChangeIcon) {
    // send message to background script
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ "newIconPath" : "newicon.png" });
}
```

Background page:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        // read `newIconPath` from request and read `tab.id` from sender
        //alert("good");
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
            path: request.newIconPath,
            tabId: sender.tab.id
        });
    });
```

Also keep in mind to register your content script's code in manifest like:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.supportedwebsiteone.com/*", "http://www.supportedwebsitetwo.com/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Don't I need access to tabs api too? That seems not accessible from content script (keeps giving undefined error). Also, I will need to know the domain name too. In short, the extension is relevant only to a few domains, but still depending on the domain different set of data will be pulled from the server and to indicate that, a different icon+badge will be displayed when a new tab is opened with a supported site or switched to a tab with a supported domain (like in adblock/disconnect shows a badge).

Comment: You don't have to access tabs api in my simple example since it's sending a request from a content script and simply using `runtime.sendMessage`: [https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) You can specify the domains in property "matches" of "content_scripts": [https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)