# Google Chrome Extension Not Working As Expected

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I'm trying my hand at a google chrome extension which in theory should be extremely straight forward. I know there are tons of stack queries and I've tried a few, I've even copied and pasted direct solutions for testing and I have been unsuccessful.  So here is the project.  When a page loads, check the html content, and change the icon programmatically.

This is my content.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.active) {
    var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
    var m = markup.indexOf("candy");
    if (m > -1) {
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "check.png"});
    } else {
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "cross.png"});
    }
  }
})
```

This is my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Tag Analyzer Plugin",
  "description": "Check if tag exist on page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "cross.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
          "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ],
  "permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

Right now I'm running this item as a content script because as a content script I can use the logic

```
var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
var m = markup.indexOf("candy");
if (m > -1) {} else {}
```

However as a content script the chrome API stuff doesn't work.  When I run this script as a background script the script works, except that

```
var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

doesn't return the pages html, it returns the injected script html.

I've read this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915311/chrome-extension-code-vs-content-scripts-vs-injected-scripts) which was informative as to what the difference was and I've read and tested many stacks like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050584/chrome-extension-read-innerhtml-of-the-current-page) this, without much success. So obviously i'm missing something and doing something wrong. Thank in advanced for any help.

**UPDATES:**

So I've made some modifications, but it's still not working, though I think that it's closer to working.

As per the comments below I am now using a content script and background script.  No errors are being thrown, however the background script isn't doesn't anything.

content.js

```
var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
var m = markup.indexOf("candy");
if (m > -1) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"found" : true});
} else {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"found": false});
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if request.found {
      alert("HERE");
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
          path: "check.png",
          tabId: sender.tab.id
      });
    } else {
      alert("HERE2");
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
          path: "cross.png",
          tabId: sender.tab.id
      });
    }
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Tag Analyzer Plugin",
  "description": "find tag on page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "cross.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
          "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ],
  "permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

I've added some alerts on the background.js to see if it was being trigger and nothing, not does the icon change.

Comment: `chrome.tabs` isn't available in a content script, see [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). You need an [event page script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages). See [chrome.tabs returns undefined in content script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15034859) and [Update chrome extension icon on tab switch/change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29173057)

Comment: I'm aware and I've already tried to move it to the background script, where as i said the code runs, but the html content of the page isn't returned, which is what I need in order to find something on it.

Comment: I copied that example you provided exactly as it is on the solution and it returns the error onSupportedPageNeedChangeIcon, minus the manifest, which I just modified to suit the example and the icon name.

Comment: kk, let me check that out :-) thanks

Comment: @wOxxOm I've made some changes. I'm still having issues if you see something.

Comment: Use the [debugger of background page](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029) and you'll see the syntax is wrong. Add parentheses: `if (request.found)`

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks! That was it, totally missed that.  If you want to submit a solution go ahead and I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks for your help.